# Breakpoints from Scala Worksheet?

Tags: scala, breakpoints, scala-ide

I'd like to perform source-level debugging when executing a Scala worksheet.

Since worksheets are evaluated automatically when saved, I can't use the "debug as" menu option like I would a normal project or file.

Is there a way to configure worksheets to run in debug mode so I can step through my code?

Answer (score 16):

This is not supported, but there is an existing Scala Worksheet [enhancement request](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/issues/50) to support this feature.